# (with )Wrapped css,js cache is not working with even same url

Tags: php, url, caching, browser-cache

**How Wrapper class works**

I created php class and now I am able to do this to put together all my css,js .It works like this `Wrap::set(array(file.css,file2.css,file3.css))` then I wrote `wrap::call_path` and it begin to generate url like this `www.example.com/wrap_contects?path[]=file.css&path[]=file2.css&path[]=file3.css`
then in the server side I get all paths with in the array then I tried `file_get_content` for each of them,after that I wrote echo all results.It put together all `CSS`,if I wrote `JS` it will be `JS`.

**Problem**

Problem is browser is not cache this url.

**Note**

I consider all security issues,I created token to send wrap_content.php to prevent file get content to work for any file that user request

Comment: Are you setting the correct http cache headers?

Comment: @jedifans in the normal css,js files was cached perfectlly,but this one is not even url is always same for same combination

Comment: If you are using php to combine files, you should set the correct expiry headers as your web server cannot figure out how long things should be cached for. With regular CSS/js files, there is a default set in the web server config for the file type to let them be cached.

Comment: @jedifans thank you I solved it with header cache control,and pragma cache

Comment: Awesome! You should create an answer and mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem,hope  it will help someone who has same problem to solve this problem in the future
I added these ones to wrap_contents.php:

```
$cache_length=60*24*30;
$cache_expire_date = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $cache_length);
    header("Expires: $cache_expire_date");
 header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000");

(if css) header("Content-type: text/css");

(if js) header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

This created css,js simulator on the response with php file.